# How correct is the statement $\int_1^∞ (\frac{1}{x^2}) \,dx= 1$?

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, improper-integrals, riemann-integration

In Calculus 2, our professor always writes something along the lines of this for improper integrals:
$$
\int_1^∞ \frac{1}{x^2} \,dx= \lim_{b\to ∞}\int_1^b \frac{1}{x^2} \,dx=\lim_{b\to ∞}\left(-\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{1}\right)=1
$$
But...this isn't technically true at all, right?$\int_1^∞ \frac{1}{x^2} \,dx$ is [not even Riemann-Integrable to begin with because the domain of integration is unbounded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Improper_integral#Examples). What I think is really happening is that
$$
\int_1^∞ \frac{1}{x^2} \,dx=DNE
$$
but...
$$
\lim_{b\to ∞}\int_1^b \frac{1}{x^2} \,dx=1
$$
Just like $\frac{e^0-1}{0}=DNE$ but $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^x-1}{x}$ converges to $1$. You wouldn't say, given a function $f(x)=\frac{e^x-1}{x}$, that
$$
f(0)=1
$$

...would you?

Comment: The latter is the *definition* of the former.

Comment: You’re correct that at face value it would be malformed as a Riemann integral, but as an improper integral we *define* it as the limit of the finite, proper Riemann integrals. So you’re not entirely off-base but the notation is actually referring to something else here

Comment: In fact $\infty$ isn't even a real number so you can't really apply the "original" definition of Riemann integral on $[1, \infty)$, but as everyone else said when we write $\int_a^\infty$ what we really mean is $\lim_{b\to\infty} \int_a^b$ by definition (of notation)

Comment: @Randall Ah...so we're just abusing notation then, aren't we? :(

Comment: I wouldn't call it abuse of notation. $\int_a^\infty$ is something not defined previously, and now we give it a definition. Abuse of notation is where the notation you're using has already been defined and you use it to denote something different from what it actually means.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you could say (if you are pedantic), that the first equality
$$
\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^2} \,dx
\color{red}{=} \lim_{b\to \infty}\int_1^b \frac{1}{x^2} \,dx
\tag1$$
is only provisional: namely, the equality holds provided the limit exists (which we do not yet know).  So keep that in mind until the computation finishes,
$$
\lim_{b\to \infty}\int_1^b \frac{1}{x^2} \,dx=\lim_{b\to ∞}\left(-\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{1}\right)=1
$$
and we see that the limit does, indeed, exist.  Then we are OK, and everything is correct.

---

I would say it is incorrect to write
$$
\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^2} \,dx=DNE
\tag2$$
when you mean
$$
\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^2} \,dx\quad\text{does not exist}.
$$
But $(2)$ is a short way of saying something, just as $(1)$ is.

Answer (score 0):

This is a convergent improper integral. Note that $\int_{1}^{\infty} 1/x^a dx$ is finite if $a>1$. It will hold even for $a=1.01$ and not hold for $a=0.99$.